# Javascript documentation generation

Tags: javascript, documentation

Im looking into documenting the javascript code we develop and are looking for some good javascript documentation generators, does anybody have any suggestions?

We used to used ndoc to create documentation for our c# code and are looking for something similar to document our js code - ideally something that can be run from a command line.

thanks in advance!

Comment: I would advise to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221413/what-tools-are-available-for-documenting-javascript) as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use famous [JSDoc-Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) for that.

> JsDoc Toolkit is an application, written in JavaScript, for
>   automatically generating template-formatted, multi-page HTML (or XML,
>   JSON, or any other text-based) documentation from commented JavaScript
>   source code.

And yes it also has [command line options](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/CommandlineOptions).

Comment: Great stuff, I'll check it out!

Comment: JSDoc-Toolkit seems no longer maintained. The site points to `jsdoc` https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

Answer (score 10):

**JSDoc** is an approach to generating documentation from commented JavaScript. There are many variations:

- It was originally implemented in Perl.
- [JSDoc-Toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) ported it to JavaScript, but requires Java as it uses the Rhino JavaScript engine written in Java.
- Several people have ported it to run directly on the [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) JavaScript engine/platform, e.g. [node-jsdoc-toolkit](https://github.com/p120ph37/node-jsdoc-toolkit).
- [dox](https://github.com/visionmedia/dox) also runs on node.js, it combines JSDoc-like tags and markdown markup but requires a separate templating engine(as used on Stack Overflow and github).

All run from the command line. Choose according to your tooling preferences. I like node.js for its speed and all-JavaScript-all-the-time feel. The DailyJS "Let's Make a Framework" [post on writing documentation](http://dailyjs.com/2011/01/13/framework-part-46/) describes these and other tools; unfortunately dox was radically overhauled to just output JSON structures since that was written.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/1221413/1162195 mentions other JavaScript documentation generators.